# lua access local function in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, lua

Is there any way to test local function with luaunit.
Here is sample code:

```
-- file f.lua
local function f (n)
    return n*2
end

-- file unit-test.lua
require('luaunit')
require('f')

TestF = {} --class
    function TestF:testF()
        assertEquals( f(5), 10)
    end
-- class TestF

LuaUnit:run()
```

When I run

```
lua unit-test.lua
```

I got:

```
Failed tests:
-------------
1) TestF.testF
unit-test.lua:13: attempt to call global 'f' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'

Ran 1 tests in 0.000 seconds
FAILED (failures=1)
```

If it's not possible what's the optimal solution for that? Should I change local function to global?

Comment: Something doesn't look right: `unit-test.lua` doesn't have line 13 and `fact` function is not mentioned anywhere. Are you sure you are showing the right files?

Comment: You cannot see local functions from outside the scope they are defined in unless something that *can* see them passes the function to you. So no, you can't do this directly like this. Your file/module would need to support "exporting" the local functions somehow.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko, thanks, fixed that.

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks for advise

Answer (score 0):

Seems, wrapping local function solves the issue:

```
-- file f.lua
local function f (n)
    return n*2
end

function wrapped_f (n)
  return f (n)
end

-- file unit-test.lua
require('luaunit')
require('f')

TestF = {} --class
    function TestF:testF()
        assertEquals( wrapped_f(5), 10)
    end
-- class TestF

LuaUnit:run()
```

After running unit-test:

> ```
> .
> Ran 1 tests in 0.000 seconds
> OK
> ```

Comment: Yes, because `wrapped_f` is no longer local and can be seen from outside the scope of the `f` file/chunk. That said a module that stuffs its functions into the global namespace directly is generally a poor citizen.

Comment: @IuriiPolishchuk: Several. You could define `f_wrapped` (or `_G.f`) only if `package.loaded["luaunit"]` is not `nil` (i.e. only when your unit tests run). Or you could put all your internal functions into a separate table and store it in `package.loaded["f.internal"]`, so that a `fint = require("f.internal")` in your test script gives you access. And then there are unit testing frameworks out there that do support testing of local functions, e.g. [this one](http://siffiejoe.github.io/lua-testy/). If you prefer luaunit, you could persuade the author to implement something similar ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should modify `f.lua` to keep module form.
So as not to pollute the global environment.

For introduction, click the below link:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

```
local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
    print("Hello World!")
end

return mymodule
```